# I got a good trend of reputation on Stack Overflow. What got me banned exactly from asking questions?

Tags: support, post-ban

Unfortunately, whenever I am going to ask new questions I am getting the error 'I have reached limit'. My latest questions had a good reception.
What's happening?

I am sorry. Maybe this is an insult on moderators when a peasant like myself try to question their reasoning behind decisions. Rather than downcasting my post without even reading, could you please let me know what got me banned exactly, so that I can improve?

Comment: Your account looks OK to me.  I suspect that there are other folks on the same IP address as you who have abusive accounts, and this is why you're being rate limited.  Only the folks at corporate know for sure.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Could be the reason, I have VPN installed in my PC for office work. Is there a way to get out of this, is this a time ban or kind of a permanent thing?.

Comment: `Is there a way to get out of this` -- Yes, visit SE on a different IP.

Comment: You have the following deleted questions: [1](//stackoverflow.com/q/47487553) [2](//stackoverflow.com/q/38261354). You have the following deleted answers: [1](//stackoverflow.com/a/51457001) [2](//stackoverflow.com/a/48032155) [3](//stackoverflow.com/a/48024451) [4](//stackoverflow.com/a/48023011) [5](//stackoverflow.com/a/47968391) [6](//stackoverflow.com/a/33968744) [7](//stackoverflow.com/a/33717189). Your account currently has a question ban. The duplicate to which this question is closed should provide you with the best information we have and the above info re deleted posts may help.

Comment: @Makyen Shouldn't have any effect on the question-asking rate limits.

Comment: @Makyen: Note that the error message is not "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account," it is "I have reached limit [sic]."

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, but the system indicates the OP's account is currently in a question ban, not a rate limit.

Comment: @Makyen: With 352 rep and two deleted questions?  Seems implausible.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Doesn't seem to work for me weirdly, quite annoying. Just posted with a new account. It's been some time since I have posted anything on SO.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well, you have a nice theory. However, as I said, the system currently states the the user has a question ban. It says that the user does not currently have a rate limit. These are separately indicated to moderators. In order for your theory to be correct, then the information provided to moderators would need to be incorrect.

Comment: @Makyen: The deleted questions that you cited are more than three years old, and the last question Mukul was allowed to ask in November got three upvotes.  This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Mukul Have you engaged in any activity that is not accounted for in your account history, like making multiple attempts to ask a question that was blocked from being posted by the automated quality filters?

Comment: @Mukul so... Is the rate limiting on this account? On the new one? You may be sending confusing signal ATM, making it harder for ppl to help (that, + throwing insults around, which is bound to backfire...)

Comment: @RobertHarvey That the ban may, or may not, be appropriate doesn't change the current state. We are, intentionally, not provided with the details of the algorithm used to determine when a question or answer ban is applied. I'm not saying that it's inappropriate to try to help Mukul. I'm *only* saying that's what the system is reporting, and that I closed the question based on the information the system is providing (which *tends* to be more reliable than what the average person provides in a paraphrased error report). The duplicate is the best information we have for people in that situation.

Comment: @RobertHarvey with 9 previous non-deleted questions having total score -9 (one of them closed and one duplicate) and two deleted ones, it makes some sense for system to wait 6 more months to allow one more question to make sure that positive shift is reliable (I learned this kiind of reasoning from some CM when I asked at MSE why they don't increase showing deleted questions to 6 months)

Comment: @Makyen: The algorithms for blocking content should forever remain a secret.  The vote thresholds for a question ban, not so much.  Everyone is free to ride the knife's edge of those vote thresholds all the way to getting a ban (which many people frequently succeed in doing).   Knowing whether you're close to being vote-banned doesn't seem like information people could use to game the system, except perhaps for downvoters who make their decisions based on those thresholds.

Comment: @gnat: Sure, but then why did the system allow Mukul to ask a question in November, one that actually improved his standing?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think this is standard thing that q-banned users are allowed to ask one question in 6 months. The thing I learned back then at MSE is that some askers dig hole too deep to get out of it with just a single positive received question, so they have to wait for 6 more months to ask a second one

Comment: That seems like an odd rule.  Six months is a long time to wait to attempt to fix your account with new, more positive questions, especially if you only get one try every six months.  That's effectively a dead account anyway.

Comment: Perhaps Mukul was question banned, deleted that account and then created a new one to try to get around the ban. The ban still applies but all those questions associated with the old account no longer appear.

Comment: @RobertLongson Well, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5506443/mukul) is the account currently under discussion.

Comment: they apparently tried to avoid even more odd cases like when someone bumped into ban after 100 questions at -10 and was relieved wirt a single question with a single upvote. Apparently heavy negative past should be taken into account somehow. The thing that looks slippery in current system is that it is absolutely insensitive to question age, a 10 years old question at -10 seems to have the same impact as one asked yeasterday, this feels a bit too straightforward to be correct

Comment: @gnat: I'm inclined to agree.  There seems to be no room for allowing someone to improve.  Old, downvoted questions should either be aged out of the ban calculation after some period of time, or given less weight.

Comment: The counterargument is that ignoring post age discourages people from doing nothing and simply waiting out the ban then continuing their poor behaviour once the ban has aged away.

Comment: less weight is exactly what I've been thinking about here. There could be some complications here, like should we account for age of the question, or age of its edits or age of downvotes but even with all these complications system would make better sense than current one (@RobertLongson if it encourages user to silently wait for 2... 3... 4 years this may turn out a good thing indeed)

Comment: @RobertLongson: Yes, but making poor-question askers wait greatly diminishes the damage created by new users, which is the real goal here.  Users who fail to reform will inevitably hit the question ban again, but they will do it by asking a downvoted question, not by asking an upvoted one as the OP has done.

Comment: @gnat: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404510

Comment: The core point is that they need to fix their < 1 scoring posts by [editing them into shape](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5506443/mukul?tab=activity). Without that effort the q-ban remains in tact. Contributing positively to the community is not achieved by doing barely nothing.

Comment: @rene: Let's be real here.  You and I both know that the likelihood of a ban being lifted by improving old questions, especially those that are deleted, is pretty much nil.  We point folks at the duplicate post, not because we're helping them to reform, but because we just want them to go away.

Comment: @rene this "edit your questions" theory was great in addressing q-ban complaints in first several years at SO - and I myself was a huge fan it. But now, enough time passed and we've got enough experience to tell for sure that this theory doesn't work as expected. So what we have now is just a stupid looking rule that 10 years old unsalvageable question blocks users from asking the same way as month-old one. I dunno, there can be some sophisticated reasoning to make it look like this approach is justified (even though its original underlying "editing theory" is long dead) but it is just stupid

Comment: @rene Thanks for all the help, It just doesn't make any sense that someone can downvote my 5/6 years old questions which can get me banned now, while at the same time you are not allowed to delete them. I just don't know how does it help with good content on the community.

Comment: “just doesn't make any sense that someone can downvote my 5/6 years old questions which can get me banned now, while at the same time you are not allowed to delete them.” - **Except looking at your reputation history this isn’t actually happening.**

Comment: What got you banned: Too many weak or bad posts. The only option you have is to improve the posts, get them undeleted, an hope you've improved them enough for the downvotes to be removed or outweighed by upvotes. I won't lie to you: This is hard.

Comment: For the record: you are no longer question banned.

Comment: 'downcasting my post without even reading' rude and abusive claim.

Comment: @Make - How exactly do you know I downvoted your question?  Voting is anonymous for a reason.  It’s to prevent one user from abusing another user because they disagree with a vote they had issued.  You indicated you received lots of downvotes to your other contributions but looking at your reputation history I didn’t see any evidence of that, and in fact, didn’t see a single downvote in the history.  Accusing me of voting your question isn’t considered to be civil behavior.  Your not a peasant by the way reputation doesn’t mean squat

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Rather than downcasting my post without even reading, could you please let me know what got me banned exactly, so that I can improve?

Well, that's the problem with question and answer bans, that we usually cannot tell you the ***exact*** reason, because the algorithm used by the engine isn't disclosed purposely. Obviously to make it harder for users to fly under the radar of that algorithm.

Though community (diamond) moderators can see (and find) all of your posts, even the deleted ones, which often are the most important triggers to step over the above mentioned algorithms limits.

As it seems now from your, and other user's comments, you've hit an edge case, where your bad received questions, asked a long time (several years) ago, are counted against you when the engine starts to analyze your overall posting scores.

There's currently a [feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404510/allow-old-poorly-asked-questions-to-eventually-age-away-for-purposes-of-the-que) discussed, that old posts should age away from the algorithm's inputs.