# Request to halve question ban duration from six months to three

Tags: feature-request, post-ban

I have gone through the [question ban](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) article and learnt that, after being banned from asking, the system will allow a time interval of six months to pass in order for that account to ask a new question if one does not edit existing questions.

This is cruel and horrible and needs to be reviewed. That time span is not even merciful to the needs of Stack Overflow users. You need to find a balancing point between punishing accounts and grace, even convicts are awarded clemency by the administration when deemed fit.

Therefore my request is to reduce the question ban duration and be fair to those that have been banned. If there is a Stack Overflow review team then I am requesting to reduce the punishment time to three months. I cannot imagine heavy users like me who run into complex tasks every now and then being banned for six months, which will be catastrophic to my career.

Comment: If being unable to ask questions for six months is *catastrophic to your career*, I believe you should reassess things -- there can be other reasons for the site to become inaccessible, and depending too much on it may not be such a good idea.

Comment: Tangentially relevant: [Allow old, poorly-asked questions to eventually age away for purposes of the question ban algorithm](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404510/1426539)

Comment: There is no other site that provides coding solutions as stackoverflow does, the best of the best can be found here, that is why I like to research on this site

Comment: Meh. It seems one has to post a lot of bad questions to get banned. *If* the duration gets reduced, at least what it takes to getting the ban should be reduced as well – better to let people know ASAP that they are on a bad track.

Comment: "*that time span is not even merciful to the needs of Stack Overflow users.*" The needs of Stack Overflow users are good questions and answers. So, having less badly received questions is most definitely in their interest.

Comment: Stack Overflow is no substitute for learning and searching. You ask questions that could be easily resolved if you have just googled first. Ban system works as it should.

Comment: You can _still_ research on the site while question-banned, it only prevents you from posting new questions.

Comment: What job requires such a wide range? - image processing, [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file processing, [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29), [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29) (in a [Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix) environment), Java, [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29), and [.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) (C#). All within a span of six weeks. Is it an internship in order to graduate?

Comment: An alternative could be to find existing questions on Stack Overflow that will answer your questions (though this is easier said than done). There are [22,427,654 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) on Stack Overflow. The answers may be in there. To quickly and efficiently search is a skill in itself. It take you into a lot of rabbit holes, but you will learn a lot in the process.

Comment: Question ban are very bad, a limit to one every 14 days would make much more sense as the user has option to improve

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Your question does not make a convincing case for why the question ban duration should be reduced. In fact, it better portrays a great example where **the question ban was merited and is serving its purpose well**, for one simple reason: Your proposal is overly focused on fulfilling the *needs of question askers*, seeking appeals for mercy and clemency towards them without considering the possible damage they can do to the platform if they continue to ask poor quality questions. Question askers are not the only stakeholders here.

[This answer of mine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/411189/1233251) explains what you might be misunderstanding about this platform.

> Stack Overflow collects ten million visits per day, which is far more than the already astounding five thousand new questions each day. We, as a community, should always be in our best interest to optimize for these ten million, which is how the site maintains its value and relevance. [...]
>
> The frustrations found during any software development endeavor are a nuisance and a reality to many folks, and the art of asking quality questions is a particularly hard one. But remember that this castle of knowledge serves an enormous universe of people with their quality questions and answers. Using the site like a helpdesk would be treating this castle like a tent.

Your description is one of a user who used the platform like a helpdesk, which works unfavorably to the goal of maintaining a quality Q&A repository. The ban made sense here.

Asking questions is, and will continue to be, a privilege, not a right. If it causes you pain and/or distress that this privilege is revoked from you, that alone is a sign that the privilege was being overly relied on. You should not depend on question asking to live your life harmoniously.

Further reading:

- [What is Stack Overflow’s goal?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254770/what-is-stack-overflow-s-goal)
- [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)
- [Is threatening new users with being blocked really the best way to improve the platform?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411187/is-threatening-new-users-with-being-blocked-really-the-best-way-to-improve-the-p)

Comment: but it can become a right if all the asking rules are followed?

Comment: @PubliusFlaviusTiberius It is never really a right, although the privilege can be assured and maintained by contributing with good quality questions.

Comment: *Asking questions is, and will continue to be, a privilege, not a right.* I agree. However, knowing that most people will just create a new account, it doesn't seem right to limit those who actually want to change.

Comment: @BlueRobin Let me be clear on that part: 1) users creating new accounts to evade limits are in violation of the terms of service, and mechanisms are in place to find and take action upon such cases; 2) even if people want to change, wanting it isn't enough. One has to show it through quality content. Otherwise, the effect is no different from those who just want answers and keep creating burner accounts to ask questions.

Comment: @E_net4 even if there are checks in place, what’s stopping someone from using a VPN or changing their IP? They would just be able to bypass it right?

Comment: @BlueRobin whoever resort to such tricks in the first place are only fooling themselves and not solving the root of their bad experience with the site. That there are ways around the current limits serves as a pretty poor excuse for giving them up anyway.

Comment: @E_net4 True, but they will still continue to post questions unsuitable for the site. Just making a new account from a different location means that they will gain back the "privilege" again.

Comment: I am becoming close to just repeating myself, @BlueRobin. Even when there are differences between written policy and technical barriers around it, that should not invite reasonable people to test its technical boundaries. Especially when knowing how to overcome the limitations earlier does not necessarily help them make good contributions and stop them from having a bad experience.

Answer (score -3):

I'll answer with a question - How does a banned member learn to ask better questions if they cannot ask new questions? The current solution is to correct your bad questions which fits in with the philosophy of having a high quality site.

If the goal of banning users is ultimately to improve the quality of the site, then lets prohibit answering down-voted questions or at least allow bad questions to be deleted, even if answered. And, if answered, apply up-votes to an answer to be applied to the downvotes of the question - if somebody provides a good answer, just how bad was the question to begin with?? Naturally, this would require answers from SO members with "non-trivial" (read "non-sock-puppet") reputation.

I personally have asked bad questions, had that pointed out to me, and, after a great big "DOH!", deleted the question. Sometimes the only fix to a bad question is to delete it. Let people fix their screw-ups instead of leaving them lay around forever just because one person spent a few minutes with an answer.

This situation reminds me of the movie "Mister Roberts".

Answer (score -9):

No this is not necessary as there is a secret script that runs and weighs your positive contributions to the site against negatives ones and decides whether or not to lift the question ban. The only way out of a ban is improving other posts and those that got you banned in the first place. But I have figure in mind but wouldn't want to expose it because once you contribute positively towards the site past that figure then the system automatically lifts the ban. Asking a question on SO is not a privilege as the company also needs the traffic to make profits so edit those articles and make everything clear.

And also please stop begging "Stackoverflow Review Team" as that team does not exist, bans are imposed by the system and not any group of persons. Suspensions and duplicate account detections are the ones that involve moderators who will notify you via the inbox that the system has detected your using two accounts and hence the two have been merged and then maybe get suspended(I speak from experience).