# Request to let banned users ask one question every week

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, post-ban

I noticed that other Stack Exchange sites allow banned users to post, but they limit the number of posts they can post per week to 1. Why wouldn't this site follow suit?

I know the system can be programmed to let banned users ask a single question every week which is not bad and fair.

So why let someone wait for six months when even the majority of the questions do not even get answered?

Comment: Why, exactly, should we allow "banned users" to post *anything at all*? The post bans kick in when someone has demonstrated a consistent history of low-quality contributions that we do not want on this platform. What benefit is it to us to allow such users to post more things that we do not want?

Comment: *"even the majority of the questions do not even get answered."* i mean, isn't that a reason to further limit asking, since there's apparently a discrepancy between askers and answerers?

Comment: Deleted questions, score <= 0, contributing to the [question ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans): [1](//stackoverflow.com/q/71711294) [2](//stackoverflow.com/q/70880214) [3](//stackoverflow.com/q/70875607) [4](//stackoverflow.com/q/70864216) [5](//stackoverflow.com/q/70517390) [6](//stackoverflow.com/q/70463783) [7](//stackoverflow.com/q/70431408) [8](//stackoverflow.com/q/70396759) [9](//stackoverflow.com/q/70255383) [10](//stackoverflow.com/q/70248747)

Comment: [11](//stackoverflow.com/q/70120675) [12](//stackoverflow.com/q/70108948) [13](//stackoverflow.com/q/70107755) [14](//stackoverflow.com/q/70105853) [15](//stackoverflow.com/q/69863134) [16](//stackoverflow.com/q/69852810) [17](//stackoverflow.com/q/69749856) [18](//stackoverflow.com/q/69625947) [19](//stackoverflow.com/q/69233608) [20](//stackoverflow.com/q/69093424) -- I think this is one of, if not the longest list I've ever seen. Your question history is perfect evidence of why 6 months is fine, or even too _low_

Comment: I am not sure why you think it is productive to repeatedly propose reducing the limits placed on users who have demonstrated an inability to contribute positively to this site. You [previously asked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417160) to cut the waiting period in half, from 6 months to 3 months. Since that was not well received, why would you think that a proposal to reduce it to 1 week would be any better received? Or [the other proposal you made to allow banned users to ask off-topic questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417376).

Comment: In all of your proposal you state that the duration needs to reduced to be *fair* to banned users. But I still lack any argument what exactly in the question ban mechanism is unfair. The only "unfair" point I can see is that you want to ask a question and are not allowed to. But that has nothing to do with fairness, more with the quality of your previous questions.

Comment: Someone needs to slide down the ask again time interval down, tomorrow is not gauranteed. :))

Comment: Neither it is guaranteed for any contributor on the network.

Comment: The truth is that you aren't really *meant* to wait 6 months. That's just the earliest time that the block expires. If you *do* come back in 6 months, the hope is that it will have given you ample time to improve your question-asking skills.

Comment: I got a contract to write a bluetooth library which can be called from a python script, I ran into problems and that's when I realized the importance of this site in helping to debug and accomplish programming objectives. A lot of my clients are canceling the contracts

Comment: You expect us to work for free so you will get paid by your client for it? Hire a freelancer if you're not able to handle your contract on your own. Or even better: Don't sell things you can't deliver. If you can't perform your work without having to ask a question on SO every week, you probably need to find another way to get enough experience.

Comment: @PubliusFlaviusTiberius "*I got a contract to write a bluetooth library which can be called from a python script, I ran into problems and that's when I realized the importance of this site in helping to debug and accomplish programming objectives. A lot of my clients are canceling the contracts*" you talk about "fairness" and yet right here you confess the only reason you want to ask questions is to make money out of the unpaid work of volunteers. Is that *fair* to contributors of the site?

Comment: Before you ask your next Meta question: no, we are not interested in allowing users to pay for the privilege of asking questions here. Independent of that, I have to agree with the other commenters that what you are claiming is in the interest of "fairness" is precisely the opposite, namely, blatant self-interest. I also have a real ethical problem with someone accepting a contract to perform a task when they lack the ability to actually perform that task. You should be honest with your customer and tell them of your limitations. If they cancel the contract, that's the best-case outcome.

Comment: The good news is all  you have to do to help yourself get out of this situation is use your next asking window to ask a good question. Then do it again when the next asking window arrives. Simply repeat this process over a few years and you'll be able to ask more frequently.

Comment: *Why* have you deleted so many questions?

Comment: The questions are all over the place: Python, Java, image processing, matrix multiplications, C#, Stone Age C programming for command-line tools under Unix, web development (JavaScript), CSV file processing without using libraries, Android, calculation of [eigenvalues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors), [principal component analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) (misspelled as *"peripheral component analysis"*), [Markov chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain), raw graphics on a canvas, etc.

Comment: There must be immense pressure to do all of this almost at the same time (within a few months). What project in the real world requires such a huge range of mathematics and technology? Are you sure it is not a fast-paced university semester? And the Bluetooth commission on top?

Comment: Or is the commission paid homework? That is one of the ways to use Stack Overflow (and many other Stack Exchange sites, for that matter). That would explain the many deleted questions.

Comment: (Also [noted a few weeks ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417160/request-to-halve-question-ban-duration-from-six-months-to-three#comment903305_417160).)

Comment: From your requirements, you or your employers would be much better off hiring a team of programmers who are adept at a wide-range of programming skills and languages. This would be a much better use of your time and of our time then continued futile discussions on meta.

Comment: Can someone share a link on where I can delete my account, am tired of everyone opening up my previous posts and downvoting them

Comment: Related meta question (now deleted - limited visibility): *[When someone posts an answer to my problem and then I get paid, is that fraud?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417642/)*

Comment: "Can someone share a link on where I can delete my account" - did you even search for how to do this before asking other people? A simple search for "how do I delete my Stack Overflow account" finds the answer - is it really too much to ask you to do *a single search* of research before you ask other people to provide you answers?

Comment: So no remorse? No intent of improving? That is disappointing. Imagine you were an unpaid volunteer.

Comment: Deleting your question won’t lift your question block. Your new account will be associated with your deleted account. You are question banned due to your own actions, specifically asking low quality questions, then deleting them after they were not well received. Your actions have proven you will continue a pattern of asking low quality questions and will simply delete them (likely even after you receive an answer)

Comment: I cannot delete, it's painful to delete after investing so much energy into this place. What about all my questions and the guys who benefitted from my bounties. Rather I stay and maybe answer dumb questions and hope they do not get down voted, maybe thats gonna get me unbanned

Comment: 'Rather I stay and maybe answer dumb questions and hope they do not get down voted'....don't bet your house on it:(

Comment: I'm not sure whether this post is even serious?  Are you trolling?

Comment: I mean, to be clear, do you actually believe that SO users should do work for you for no wage?  I'm sure there's a word for that....

Comment: A new account it is, am gonna tunnel the IP address because that is what they use to merge accounts with. Maybe use Nord VPN or but a new account  is must, I have to cheat around this.

Comment: I'm skeptical that most contributors in good standing, with a history of posting well-received questions, post questions any more than once per week. I myself have only done that three times over eight years, but nearly all of those were question/answer pairs around new releases meant to inform the community of solutions I found to new problems, and not asking for help. Once a week seems like a high frequency for posting new questions, and _especially_ for someone with a history of posting poorly received questions.

Comment: and that is why your reputation is 5k, you need to ask and post more to get better, isn't that the point of this site?

Comment: @PubliusFlaviusTiberius No, the point of this site is to create a repository of useful questions and answers.

Answer (score 33):

There is already rate limiting in place that does this. This is the first step that the site takes to protect itself from poor quality questions. If you continue to ask poor quality questions then you will eventually hit the automatic question ban. This is the same for all sites across the network. The thresholds might vary, but the route is the same: first you are rate-limited; then you are banned.

However, if you start to ask better questions *before* you are banned then the rate limits will be lifted.

Comment: I got an important question to ask but am banned, and we got like hundred thousand questions asked which will not be answered, that was my point and maybe if they would let me ask, I would get help

Comment: Your "important question" may be considered important by you but in reality it is no less or more important than every other question on the site.

Comment: @PubliusFlaviusTiberius the fundamental problem exhibited here is that you're viewing the community as a service to you, rather than viewing yourself as a contributing member of the community. "Importance" should be gauged by whether your contributions add value to the community foremost. Participation is a privilege, not a right. Benefits to you will follow: a well-organized and curated community makes it easy to find answers without having to ask. Asking thoughtful, original, on-topic questions means you'll get upvotes and solutions as well as provide a resource for future visitors.

Comment: @PubliusFlaviusTiberius: _"...we got like hundred thousand questions asked which will not be answered..."_ That only reinforces the point. Often, questions aren't answered because they're not well-formed. Maybe they lack enough detail, are too broad, or are difficult to understand. Many of those get closed. Allowing people with a proven history of asking such questions is only going to _increase_ the number of unanswered questions, thus increasing the _noise_ for the community to sort through. We'd rather have 100 high-quality, focused questions than hundreds of thousands of poor questions.