# Where can I ask questions like can someone convert this code to xyz language?

Tags: support, scope, asking-questions

Where can I ask questions like can someone convert this code to xyz language?

I don't think it should go to Stack Overflow. Where can I do that?

Comment: On a "hire a dev" site?

Comment: Don't ask "can someone convert this for me?". Like @Tom mentioned that isn't a question for [so], it's a request for someone to do the work; such "questions" can be very poorly received. Instead try to convert the code yourself, and when/if you get stuck, show the specific part you are stuck on in the original language, *explain* what it does, and show your attempt(s) to get the same behaviour. If it's documentation/articles you don't understand when trying to convert, cite those.

Comment: Nowhere here, I hope and pray. Doing someone else's work for them should *never* be the purpose of this site. As far as are there other non-SO sites for this question? I honestly don't know and don't care.

Comment: There are tools for *automatic* conversion (I have used Pascal-to-C and Visual Basic-to-C# converters successfully). Site *[Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour)* ***may*** accept such questions about them (I can't imagine Stack Overflow would).

Comment: Easy. 1) Go to [Fiverr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiverr). 2) Commission it. 3) Some will [subcontract the work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417632/request-to-let-banned-users-ask-one-question-every-week#comment906275_417632) to unpaid volunteers on Stack Overflow (and saving you the embarrassment) 4) Hope for the best.

Comment: Give it a try and then post what you have done so far, but really try it first your self, before here asking, else it would be to braid

Comment: No, questions like this are definitely not permitted here. Please see: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: If you approach this from another direction, perform the translation and ask targeted questions about problems you had with the attempt, you'll have decent success. That said don't translate code. Understand the source code's observable behaviour and implement the behaviour in the new language. Translating code is like translating any language. You need to capture the intent and nuances, not the literal meaning, otherwise you get gibberish like [All Your Base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_your_base_are_belong_to_us).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I am not sure if anyone would do it for free. You can check out one of many freelancers sites out there.

At the end of the day if you need someone to write code for you, you have to hire them or bribe in some other way.

It's really less of a question and more of a request.