# Should reputation decay?

Tags: discussion, reputation

The "problem": Reputation should help to show how reputable a *user* is, hence the name. It does that for many users, however it creates a sort of 'unfairness'. People who, a long time ago, asked simple, common, questions which, at this point would be booted for not being up to "community standard", get their at most 200 rep per day years after it has been posted, with their newer contributions making up a minor part of their reputation.

Example: What is the highest *reputation* for someone very active in the last five years, and is it possible to be in the top 0.02% like someone, who has been active for three years, and hasn't posted actively since 2011 [account in question](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3153/brian-r-bondy)? This is a cherry-picked example of course, but there are many like it. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4883/readonly) for example.

Even those of the olden times that are still actively posting probably get most of their rep from the olden times.

This is because every question has been asked already, and the "Wikipedia of Programming" now is a Q&A forum like any other. This is another issue that is honestly a bit bleh. I dare to say that if SO was just a repo of knowledge and troubleshooting, by far most has been explored already and all that stay are specific and individual questions that don't get any traction, hence neither do the answers.

The youngest question in the top 50 is from 2013, in the top 100 from 2014, in the top 200 then you find something from 2016, even on page 40 (50 questions per page) there are still more posts from the 2000s than the 2010s. In the top 2000 posts I didn't find anything from the last three years.

That doesn't mean our questions nor answers have been worse; they are just not as wide-spread and popular. Unasked questions for new technology rise a bit, but are still too fringe to be as widely seen as anything in the most common, basic languages like C, Python or Java.

The point is - reputation is not an elitist thing that you have if you've been active early, or have much less of if you are even much more active now. It is a outdated form of measurement that isn't representative of the user and their involvement in the community, and is harder to get now than ever. Say what you will about [Reddit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reddit), but due to the lack of limitations on content, if you want to get a lot of karma you can, and new "most upvoted" posts come out every day with more users and more content and so on, something that is not possible here, as I said before the content is running out, and as such also the incentive for help (rep+ make neurons brrr) is reduced.

Most people don't help for rep, but I am sure it keeps a lot of them to stay and try to get more. The top account of Reddit, not posted due to [NSFW](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/NSFW#Adjective), has started posting in 2018. I wonder if someone can tell me the top user position of any account created 2018 or later...

Anyway, after way too much monologue, either get a new "activity score" additionally to rep that shows the rep of the last, I don't know, one year. Cap old posts or give a factor to the rep. (recent post 2x rep, one year ago 1x rep, five years ago 0.5x rep, etc).

Or find another way to make it possible to 'climb the ranks', if rep isn't something to show off, why is it shown?

Also I am not complaining about me not getting any rep. I don't want this question to be applied to or put into relation with me, and this is just a thought that I had. Maybe it isn't an issue and I am the only one thinking about this and SO is actually not declining in quality and users ([isn't it though](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347610/what-are-the-number-of-active-participants-joining-stack-overflow-every-day)) I don't know! But apparently it isn't something new, [this post from 2014](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252756/are-high-reputation-users-answering-fewer-questions) is talking about something similar, but apparently nothing is happening.

Comment: There's already a _daily reputation cap_ of 200, so what?

Comment: Why do you need reputation points? They're mostly used in curation activities and yet your post seems to advocate against curation. Why have the rep then?

Comment: Just ignore reputation - life gets so much more relaxed  :)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Idk if you overread that but I am talking about this. this user has 90.000 rep from one question, which, if asked today, would be deleted for low-quality https://stackoverflow.com/users/13161/mattshane it is also his only contribution. he is better than 99.82% of all users?

Comment: I don't think the problem is that this user has 90k rep, but that all of it came from a single post. We have no way to determine if they are actually good site curators and yet they gained all the privileges.

Comment: Sure, the rep system isn't perfect, but I don't really see that this causes any major issue. So what if mattshane has an 'undeserved' high rep, as long as they don't abuse it in anyway, it's nbd.

Comment: @Dharman because it is, after all, a measurement of quality and reputabilty of an account but not really representative of either of those. as i said i don't care about my rep personally, i am not salty about having so little - i do however see this as another symptom in the stagnating if not sinking ship that is SO.

Comment: If you think that people retaining reputation for old posts is stagnating Stack Overflow then I think you should provide some concrete evidence for this in your question.

Comment: @Dharman that also is what i was talking about with the multiplicator for rep, he still gets about 8000 rep PER YEAR for this post, and has been for the last few years. it is unfair, to some extent, and unrepresentative of the user

Comment: @Dharman I think if that was the core issue of SO i woudln't be the one to unravel it. But nonetheless it is, in my opinion, an issue and since it is far from the only issue it is also in my opinion worth discussing.

Comment: I am trying to understand your train of thought, but I am still missing something. So you're saying that if we reduce the reputation of older accounts, it will help to encourage more reputable users to participate more? Isn't this just tying a shorter carrot and expecting the donkey to go faster?

Comment: How is it unfair, @MaritnGe ?

Comment: @Dharman whether it is intended as such or not, rep is a reward and something people compare. not all, but a lot. What these 'effortless rep millionairs' do is create a field where, due to the overloaded nature of SO, already find it hard to write successfull content, especially if they are unlucky enough to be in any saturated field, it is hard to accumulate rep. not impossible, but hard. If a user helps 10 people a day and gets 1-2 votes from each answer he'll take a very long time to be 'reputable' by just the rep alone, even though he is objectively more helpful now than the many dead accs

Comment: What you are describing is called **envy**

Comment: @MaritnGe Can you describe how current users are "objectively more helpful now than the many dead accs "? Users who have the same problem now will find it helpful if they find an old answer which solves their problem now. That's why they upvote old questions and answers. How is this not helpful for current users who face the same problem?

Comment: Is there a single post across the entire network that's been getting minimum 20 upvotes a day for years? I have a post that was highly popular and gained reputation cap for about half a week, but by no means is it a significant source of rep for the long term. The bigger source of rep are the 2k+ other answers.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz may sound stupid but a helpful question does not imply a helpful user. continuty, commitment, friendlyness and general activity should be rewarded more. An old question is surely helpful but that doesn't mean that the user is.

Comment: @KevinB only a sith deals in extremes. but as the user i picked out earlier shows that you can get about 5000 rep per year from one single post from a long time ago

Comment: We have no way to reward user on the site, so there's no way to reward "continuty, commitment, friendlyness and general activity". Maybe there should be something like this, but currently the main way to gain reputation is by providing helpful questions and answers.

Comment: "only a sith deals in extremes", but lets single out a single user that earned an unusual amount of rep and use that as evidence to punish everyone network-wide with decaying reputation.

Comment: This question cites *one* case where the problem occurs and the solution might apply. How many actually are there, i.e. how significant is the problem? Is there a practical problem, i.e. do these accounts get misattributed competency in day-to-day use? The major issue with citing just one case is that we have lots of other cases and it is not clear how the "solution" would apply there. Are people racing for rep ("FGITW") encouraged to produce better content this way? Would active curators – who already pay for things with rep – be able to keep on curating?

Comment: @KevinB there are many more like that, i literally went top from the top 10 questions and picked the first that applied, like https://stackoverflow.com/users/3219/danail-nachev who gets about 2000 rep per year and got most from 1 of his from 30smt posts, or https://stackoverflow.com/users/900412/g-inherit with also 2000 per year from 2 posts. this is nothing rare

Comment: so, maybe a few dozen people at most?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi i just posted 2 more extreme cases, but I am also sure most still active old users get most of their rep from old posts. I don't have any data, but https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet has all of his top posts in the early 10s late 00s. Did his answers/questions become worse? I don't think so, it is just harder now to get rep. 1rep now is worth more than one rep in ye early days

Comment: Jon Skeet gets enough rep from his 35k answers that he'd not miss the daily rep cap if the outliers were removed.

Comment: You want to redesign the site because of outliers that get lots of rep from a few answers? You design things to work best for the many, not the few.

Comment: @RobertLongson yes, and for most people reputation is a thing that is out of reach that you could've gotten easier if you came to the site a decade ago or more. even in 20 years if this site still exists there aren't gonna be many questions that will break through to the top. are these questions objectively worse, and are the posters not as helpful, or is the site just simply oversaturated and not really made for the purpose it is filling now

Comment: Earning rep is easy. you just have to *earn* it. Go post answers. Taking rep away from everyone else doesn't help that problem. There are people who have still reached 20k rep in less than a year recently.

Comment: @MaritnGe Since you've now repeatedly tied rep to *posts* – are you concerned about the appearance of *users* or *questions/answers*? No amount of reweighting reputation will affect the result of asking "are these questions objectively worse".

Comment: There are only **eleven** users (according to this [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1622374/high-rep-uses-from-1-question)) who have got 25,000 or more reputation (and thus all the privileges) from a single post; that really isn't a large percentage of the user base, it's a tiny amount.

Comment: You can post a lot of good answers today and come back in 10 years. You will see how much reputation you gained by that time.

Comment: @Larnu ok and increase that to 2 and you have 21, and with 5 posts or less you have 71. If you go up to 50 posts, which isn't really a lot, especially to get full perms, you have 4885 users. Using 1 is a bit extreme because most people post more than once, but still get that 'one hit wonder' to blast them into space. Because i am sure of those 4885 users, most aren't actually that helpful or active still

Comment: What harm does these users having rep cause? Does seeing other users with high rep make you not want to participate?

Comment: I have to wonder something here. Say that that number was not named "Reputation" but "internet points". Would you have still created this meta post? Because there is one opinion that I have and that is that "reputation" was a really poor choice of description. It's more like a janitor status, the higher the number the more voluntary cleanup duties open up to you.

Comment: *"Using 1 is a bit extreme because most people post more than once"* yet you already did that [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419564/should-reputation-decay#comment920717_419564).

Comment: @Larnu i was picking out one user as example, not create a dataset where you can effortlessly get all the data you want.

Comment: @Gimby that is a good point actually, i don't know

Comment: The majority of users, however, have [several hundred](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1622375?BracketSize=10) posts @MaritnGe . A minority of people does not make the norm.

Comment: To be a bit more productive... Do you intend decay to depend on *post* age or *vote* age? Say I have an old post that I edit regularly to keep it up-to-date and it garners many votes after a recent edit, how would those be counted?

Comment: I'd argue that reputation decaying, may actually act as a diminishing effect... if new users are aware of that system up front. If you know that if you began to participate, you'd only retain your reputation as long as you continued to participate and never be able to rise above a certain threshold based on how much you're able to participate, would you even begin? (assuming you were here for reputation, not help, ofc)

Comment: Like, look at it from my perspective, i'd be losing rep every day, even though i'm here participating every day... my participation simply doesn't generate reputation. Even if i did start answering, i'd need to be answering at a level that matches the decay, and if that decay is based on my past posts, it'd be quite harsh given how active i was early on.

Comment: There is always going to be imbalance and the existence of an extreme edge case is not a sign of everything going to sh*t everywhere. Do you think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1604212/61305) is worth 18,000 reputation (about 7% of my total spread across over 4,300 answers)? I don't. I also think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11485101/61305) was worth more than 0, but this is life. Life is unfair, some effort is rewarded differently, sometimes it's hard to tell how much a simple answer will help other users while a much more complex answer (or a lot of them!) won't.

Comment: Maybe a warning when you upvote a post from 2010: *Are you sure this ancient stuff is useful today*.

Comment: @rene Don't give them any ideas...

Comment: This is an interesting idea, granted, but it's one that becomes immediately non-viable when you consider that site privileges are currently rep-gated, and you've only apparently considered answers (and maybe questions) as a way to maintain reputation. If other things like edits and reviews (content moderation, not just content creation, in other words) contributed to reputation (or at least prevented this decay), then you might have something.

Comment: Reputation points? Easy. Just enter the [Pandas sweatshop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) and start to work (it [has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73199427/) now expanded to [R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) as well, if you are into the exotics). It probably wouldn't be difficult to write your own homework generator, either. Some people get reputation points and some people don't have to [pay for homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417632/request-to-let-banned-users-ask-one-question-every-week#comment906279_417632). Everyone is happy.

Answer (score 11):

> The youngest question in the top 50 is from 2013, in the top 100 from 2014, in the top 200 then you find something from 2016, even on page 40 (50q per page) there are still more posts from the 2000s than the 2010s. In the top 2000 posts I didn't find anything from the last 3 years.

So in conclusion, posts that have been around longer and helped more people have had more time to collect more votes. Sure.

> Unasked questions for new technology rise a bit but are still too fringe to be as widely seen as anything in the the most common, basic langs like C, Python or Java.

New technologies appear all the time. The Swift programming language has only been around [since 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_(programming_language)) so nobody's going to have questions from 2010.

Existing popular programming languages also gain new features. There aren't going to be questions or answers about [C++ lambda capture](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0409r2.html) before 2017

[Temani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif) for instance has been around for 4 years and seems to have had no problem 'climbing the ranks'.

My own experience is that a few answers do hit the mark and get regular upvotes but I'd have struggled to predict in advance which ones they would be. I guess if you try to pin the tail on the donkey often enough, a few times you'll get really really close by accident.

I also probably answer fewer questions now than I used to but that's because I'm answering questions in a niche (SVG) that hasn't changed much in the last few years and so it's easier and easier to mark new posts as duplicates and thereby instantly help people despite that probably being the lower rep way to go. I could move onto a field that is newer or more rapidly changing but then so could anyone.

Comment: There are a lot of users who are able to climb up the ranks quickly. It's just a matter of finding the right topics to ask and answer. But is this really an answer to the question OP asked?

Comment: @Dharman Refuting the premises of the question is an answer if the premises the question is based on are inaccurate or incorrect. Once you've done that you can't reach the same conclusion the OP wants to.

Comment: of course there can't be swift questions asked in 2010, i don't get your point it almost comes across condescending. but if you believe that questions for newer technologies have no place in the top questions sure thing. you also have to separate the user from the post. a good question does not mean the user is good, you need a lot of good questions. the user you posted has also posted an immense amount of answers, but he still has a very low rep/answer compared to older accounts. he is working much harder for the same outcome, and the thing is called "reputation" not "helpfullness", so even

Comment: i don't see the comments so i lost  my train of thought. anyways, you have on avg 297 rep per post, the user you posted has 32. are you almost 10x as helpful as him? or did you just come to the site early and get lucky in a very few early answers that got big, or did your quality of answer decline and you get fewer rep now?, because i don't think so, you still wanna help people and you still do so well. but you tell me please, of your 112k rep, how much is from content before, let's say, 2016

Comment: No, I have 49 rep per post (111500 / 2265) Temani has (216719 / 6695) or 32 rep per post. Not very different given that some of my answers have had 6 more years to get votes.

Comment: sorry that is my bad, i was seeing the questions on the meta profile. anyways, could you answer the second part of my comment? not as a 'gotcha' thing, i am actually curious

Comment: @MaritnGe I've updated my answer with some observations about my circumstances. Maybe I'm not typical though.

Comment: @MaritnGe My rep per post is 61, heavily weighted by the single answer I highlighted above. I don't think such a simple calculation can possibly be indicative of my helpfulness now or at any point or range in the past, so I'm not sure what value it adds to the conversation.