# Influx of poor quality questions from 1K+ users

Tags: discussion, questions, reputation

Lately I notice a significant amount of really poor quality questions from users that, according to their rep, should know better.

They barely state the problem and ask for solutions, sometimes "most efficient".  No notion of trying anything first.

I remember that in infamous "Documents" times there were accumulators of easy rep. But they were subsequently removed.

Did I miss any new flood gates being opened?

Comment: I don't think that there is something like "Documents"... I have seen the same on  [tag:google-sheets], [tag:google-apps-script]. Have you noticed this on specific tags?

Comment: @Rubén: I see them in multiple tags for popular programming languages. I can understand that someone proficient in one language/technology could be just a starter in some other. But while collecting their rep they were inevitably exposed to basic site requirement, right?

Comment: Well, I think that there are some tags that might attract people that doesn't care too much about the "proper" use of upvotes/downvotes... i.e. there might be people upvoting as "I like" "Me too" rather than "Shows research; it's clear and useful", enough to make bad askers get >1k+ or the askers have being posting enough to get that rep from those "careless" voters.

Comment: We need to downvote more.

Comment: "Documents" probably refers to the ill-fated "[Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation)" project ([2015](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow)-2017). Yes, two full years (though most people ignored it shortly after it launched, because it immediately filled up with junk that was impossible to remove or change).

Comment: Re *"Lately I notice ... new flood gates being opened"*: Well, it was [September](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September) only a few days ago... And it is/was Sunday and homework is due Monday. And some are for [paid homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417632/request-to-let-banned-users-ask-one-question#comment906279_417632). Some of those users, that post on behalf of others, could have more than 1,000 reputation points). ***Do you have some examples?*** The more, the more the [meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225) (if any) will be spread out.

Comment: To clarify, while "*They barely state the problem ...*" could mean the question is unclear, and "most efficient" could be opinion-based, the "*ask for solutions*" and "*No notion of trying anything first.*" are not problems really. Questions that directly state a problem clearly do not need to show any attempt at solving the problem, and in fact are better without a failed attempt (unless the attempt is *necessary* to describe the problem). At the moment this question just reads a bit like a rant, and would benefit a lot from a much clearer description of what problem you've observed.

Comment: @PeterMortensen - I purposely did not include any samples just to avoid meta effect.

Comment: @PM77-1 If you're not going to include examples then there's no way for us to determine whether you're correct in your assertion or not. And if we cannot determine that, we cannot determine the answer to this question. Therefore I have voted to close this.

Comment: Could it just be a perception problem? You're *noticing* these more now, rather than the *actual rate* of these increasing?

Comment: It was just [September](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September).

Comment: I wanted to add a smiley face.  The question was asking about why are so many unclear questions coming in and closed because it was an unclear or needed clarification, research.  lol

Comment: Maybe it's an issue of what is considered a 'good quality' question. I've been part of SO for years, moderated hundreds of posts, and there are many classified as 'too broad', while actually being great questions, with no answers on line. We leave those authors with nothing, just because it doesn't fit the strict pattern. IT is far more complex than 'how do I fix that error?' which SO focuses on. One thing is to close repetitive, pointless discussions, other to shut down useful stuff only because it's not a 100% precise questions. This is where I hit a wall myself recently, disappointing.

Comment: @mikus probably not