# Is the New Question Form for New SO User's Working to Prevent Low Quality Questions? (maybe a revisit?)

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, quality-filter, ask-question-wizard

This time of year Stack Overflow seems to get bombarded with numerous low-quality questions. That's understandable. It's about a month and a half into the fall semester and burgeoning programmers are beginning to panic under the weight of their current CS course. I know we went though a redesign and even a guided new question page (if I recall correctly) that was aimed at preventing this issue. I don't have any metrics or way to see how worked out, but I do know what I see on SO.

Over the past week or so there have been the normal numerous low-quality questions, ultimately closed, but often leave the new user soured on SO unlikely to return. (e.g. [how to save data fast in c++ (adding text to meet quality standards)(Screw Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74073767/3422102)). I wonder if a revisit of how the new question flow is working may be able to avoid that. I hate to see first questioner's, through obvious haste on their part, turned away thinking they just received "get lost" from the site.

It's a difficult problem, they should have spent more time navigating to learn how, balanced against human-nature in the internet age of "just click the button".

My only thought is that for low-rep users, pick your rep-limit, they have a clear "Before you Ask:" set of steps to review and confirm before they get to post their question. I think it is somewhat like that now, but perhaps a confirmation of each the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page, the [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page and [How to create a Minimal Complete Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) might mitigate this a bit.

This is just a topic for discussion, not a critique, on where both question quality and PR may be helped. This was sparked by the cited question a few minutes ago and it seemed worth bringing up here. On balance the devs always make the right call, so I'll leave it to you to see if anything can be tweaked here.

Comment: They are working on the [staging grounds](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/staging-ground)

Comment: If only that OP knew that this site is utterly incompatible with the attitude presented by the phrase _"I just want to know how to save data to a binary file FAST!!!"_... That example could have been prevented from the start by setting expectations right.

Comment: What existing guidance would inform a user unfamiliar with the network that questions like that aren't going to have a positive outcome most of the time?

Comment: My thought was have the `[ ] I have read ....` check for each of the introductory pages that explain About, How to ask and MRE. That way, if the question is still bad, there is no question the fault is all on the user and they cannot complain about any response they get from SO. Again, that's just a thought. I don't know if there is a better way to reinforce it, I don't do site design. Maybe what we have is as good as it gets. I just wanted to see if there was anything that might mitigate either the question quality or user response.

Comment: And have the `[ ] I have read ....` at the bottom of the page, so they must scroll through it. Or perhaps a check box for each paragraph within the pages (though that gets a bit cumbersome depending on the page). I'm just searching for something that cuts down all the `[Closed]` questions on the list that get by the initial screening.

Comment: Right, but like, putting myself in their shoes... and reading the now deleted questions... I don't see any guidance there that would say re-asking an old question to get new answers is unlikely to go well. The only thing I see if suggesting they link to the other "outdated" posts, however even in this case that wouldn't have had a more positive result. Having the user assert that they've read X Y and Z doesn't alleviate the feeling of rejection or answer whatever problem they're having that isn't being solved by existing posts. they want the help-desk service that SO presents itself to be.

Comment: Another idea would be Notice. Have a big banner at the start that reads `"Failure to follow the guidelines for asking A question will result in your question being downvoted and closed."` That would be another way to impart upon the new user the gravity of failing to follow the SO guidelines. The more they understand the consequences up front I think mitigates against the hard-feeling they get when their question is closed. Something like that leaves no doubt.

Comment: They did not read any of the existing text about asking good questions, so why would you expect them to read any new text?

Comment: That's the purpose of the question here. Can we do something to ensure the existing text is read and confirmed. Or incorporate whatever the latest best practices are for communication instructions in a web interface are. If what we have is the best we can do, that's fine. Though I've never seen a revisit on any issue not turn up some room for improvement, be it in hospital standards of care or vehicle fuel system safety design or any issue in between. Based on what I see on SO, it's worth another look and seeing if there is anything else that will help.

Comment: You mean, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice)?

Comment: Recent similar: *[Influx of poor quality questions from 1K+ users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420648/)*

Comment: "This time of year Stack Overflow seems to get bombarded with numerous low-quality questions." - that's the entire year though. Perhaps in this time of the year you choose to look more closely? :)

Answer (score 5):

## No<sup>†</sup>.

<sup>†: [Not until we can measure its effectiveness, anyway.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378070/1079354)  The company at large [seems content with saying "it's doing a thing"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418491/1079354) but if you're seeing anecdotally that the thing the system was meant to be doing doesn't actually work, then *perhaps*, just *perhaps*, it's **not** doing a thing??</sup>

Answer (score -2):

Trying to intimidate new users won't work. It targets the wrong new users. That gives other sites more ammunition to talk about how *unfriendly* Stack Overflow is. Meanwhile people will still sign up, copy-paste their homework, roll the dice on someone being willing to ignore ethics and FGITW out an answer, and leave whether or not they get an answer.

I don't think simply making them check boxes will work, either. We live in the age of EULAs; people will check boxes without reading, and it *doesn't help us* to be able to say "look, you checked the boxes, you clearly didn't actually read, this is your fault". By and large, people will still sign up, etc. They won't stick around to be blamed, and won't care if they are. Worst case, you'll get some people insisting up and down that they did read and that the how-to-ask pages etc. don't say the things that they actually do.

(After all, they already insist up and down that they spent hours researching and couldn't find anything, when I can find tons of relevant results by copying and pasting the relevant part of the error message, or even *their own complete question title* into DDG. I've even had people continue insisting about this *after* I show the search results, while refusing to elaborate on why those search results aren't helpful.)

I propose that any system to filter new users has to actually *prevent* posting until we *know* that they've absorbed the community standards. (I expect here that people who are simply lazy are the majority of the problem, not people who are actively malicious.) So, **quiz them**. Require correct answers to questions that test the material in How to Ask etc., before questions may be posted.

The Staging Ground is another step in the right direction. I continue to believe that, site-wide, questions need to *start in a closed state* (there are, of course, many other things that have to be changed around that in order to have a full working proposal; so this is just an off-hand observation).

An ounce of prevention, etc.

Comment: My brother in Christ, I say this with as much force as you can feel from a digital interface:  **I do not give a good g[redacted] about whether or not people think Stack Overflow is friendly.  Those kinds of people can go pound sand.**

Comment: I mean, I agree, but bad PR is bad PR.

Comment: No seriously, it doesn't matter anymore Karl.  There are people who have already formed their calcified opinions of Stack Overflow and its policies on how people ask questions, and while *a lot of them* do get excoriated over posting their homework or their daily work assignment here, *a lot **more** of them* still come back to the site and are constructive and are able to use the site in such a way that doesn't cause them the same level of angst.  Oh, there's also the fact that the site keeps coming up high in search results - because we curate this place, damn it.  So it's whatever anymore.

Comment: ...I don't understand how that translates into an objection to my overall answer.

Comment: It wasn't really an objection.  I'm just saying that your concern about the population which we can't reach is misplaced.  Just because others willfully disregard the policies we have doesn't mean we shouldn't enforce 'em.

Comment: It was not in any way my intent to propose a lack of enforcement. Quite the opposite.