# What can I do to have my questions about Google's Looker Studio reopened?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

I have two questions that I need opened and I have done everything I can to meet the criteria.  I don't understand what more is needed.  Why were they closed and how do I get them opened? I feel that closing a question right away is the wrong approach if it's not a duplicate.

[View order doesn't change on report level controls on Looker Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74409587/view-order-doesnt-change-on-report-level-controls-on-looker-studio)

[Find average amount of occurances per user_id in Google data studio (looker)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74310759/find-average-amount-of-occurances-per-user-id-in-google-data-studio-looker)

Comment: AKA [Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/overview) (GDS). [Tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-data-studio/info). Apparently the renaming took place on 2022-10-11. It will cause confusion to not mention the old name.

Answer (score 11):

Both questions don't look to be a good fit for Stack Overflow. One of the questions doesn't look to be related to the site scope, the other one might be, but it doesn't include enough details to be certain whether it's about programming or about the use of software without involving any programming.

---

Please bear in mind that this site is for questions from people who write code about... writing code and using tools to do that.

- Questions about general use of software are off-topic
- Questions that don't show what was tried to write code or using tools to do that could be closed. Usually they are closed as being unclear, not having enough details.
- Questions that only include requirements usually are closed too.

For basic guidance on asking questions here, use the Ask Wizard → [The Ask Wizard (2022) has graduated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421038/1595451)

---

As mentioned [by Daedalus in a comment to this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421477/two-questions-about-googles-looker-studio-have-been-closed-and-i-cant-get-them/421478?noredirect=1#comment934082_421478), previous questions that don't follow the site guidelines and have answers should not be used to demand to the community to accept another question. Please bear in mind that the site moderation is done by a large number of volunteers and still the site gets a very large number of questions every day, so some questions might "slip through the cracks" or might found interesting to be used as a seed for an answer to later be used as reference / FAQ / duplicate target.

Comment: I disagree.  There are quite a few similar questions to mine.  How is this question any different? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60769183/data-studio-date-range-filter-on-hour-minute-level/60769415#60769415

Comment: @brink The existence of questions that break the rules do not mean your question(s) that break the rules are allowed.  The only thing it means is that they slipped through the cracks, and now that attention was brought to them, they will be dealt with accordingly.

Comment: Would you like me to list the hundreds of other similar questions as well?  It seems that the rules are applied arbitrarily, not questions slipping through the cracks.

Comment: Mind you, the person who answered that question is the same one who commented on mine and voted it down.

Comment: @brink How about you use your flag privileges to do that; we have review queues that will address those flags(in time).  Remember however that this site, as well as other popular sites in the network see a near constant stream of questions.  Plenty slips through the cracks.

Comment: @Daedalus I appreciate the clarity.  Not all stack exchange sites adhere to such a strict policy and I never post to stack overflow.

Comment: As the primary close voter - This answers covers the main points. [#1 View...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74409587) is technically Caused by a Typo (see comment 2), though it lacks a [mre]. [#2 Find...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74310759) was an image based question, when closed, and while details were added, the expected output is not clearly shown (e.g. Paul = 3 (a, b, c), etc) and additionally there is no code attempt (not a close reason) e.g. using `COUNT_DISTINCT`... would show the expected output in a table, serving as a base to build a question of - "*How to `SUM` `COUNT_DISTINCT`?*"

Comment: @brink: Yes, some sites (effectively) work as [help desks, forums](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour), [script writing services](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour), and [homework help](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour). They don't intend to build anything of lasting value. Which is probably fine. But not the corruption (paid homework). [Some tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) work the same way, possibly amplified by [the payment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417632/#comment906279_417632).