# What is wrong with my answer and why did I get downvoted for a working answer?

Tags: discussion

[Here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74656236/how-to-join-multiple-tables-together-in-sql-server/74656516#74656516) to a post that I gave a good answer (good = the code does what the user is expecting) with an explanation of the code itself.

This is my answer:

[image: Eenter image description here]

Whoever gave me a downvote didn't leave a comment with any constructive criticism, and since I'm relatively new to the site and I want to improve both my questions and answers, I'd like to ask why did I get a downvote for?

Is my explanation bad, is it bad formatted or did I maybe misunderstand the question, although as I already said, the expected output is the same as the output my code would give?

Comment: People downvote for any number of reasons. My guess (and it is a guess) from the comments is that the question was seen as just a "give me the code" question or was seen as too unclear to give a definitive answer - some people downvote any answers to such questions.

Comment: Best to ignore down-votes and move on. Also, consider being more selective in choosing which questions to answer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Then whats the point in having downvotes? They should also be a signal to the asker/answerer, not only other visitors, that their post isn't useful. When they ignore downvotes they continue creating unhelpful content.

Comment: @Tom: the specific point about down-votes is a flag to future visitors your view on the  utility of the question or answer. And by "ignore" I should have been more specific: best not to post a meta post about a down-vote, especially if it is only 1 or 2 DV's, if only to avoid the [Meta Effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect). While the meta effect is *sometimes* in your favor, most often it is not.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels ok, that's better. They should still try to learn why such posts get downvotes to improve the quality of future posts.

Comment: @Tom: no disagreement here

Comment: A guess is that the downvote is a signal that you shouldn't answer homework dumps AKA work orders (which are also likely to be duplicates). They also delete the question as soon as they can or are allowed after extracting the value (getting an answer), removing the value (if any) from (most) everybody else, [paid homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417632/request-to-let-banned-users-ask-one-question-every-week#comment906279_417632) or not.

Comment: @PeterMortensen "Work orders" are not particularly likely to be duplicates (although some popular courses keep using the same questions), but they are likely to *contain* one or more duplicates (i.e. a duplicate is what remains after the asker has done enough work to create a question that is suitable at all).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> (good = the code does what the user is expecting)

No, that is not even **close** to the only requirement, or to the standard expected.

To avoid downvotes on answers, the most important step is to **not** answer bad questions. At all times, keep in mind that Stack Overflow is **not a discussion forum**. The key consequence of this is that we have a very high standard for questions. (Or at least, one that - when properly applied - excludes almost everything that is asked. Personally, I think this says more about the questions than the standard, but...)

The question here (now deleted) is a plain requirements dump. It doesn't try to explain what actual difficulty is being encountered; and it imposes a constraint that doesn't make a lot of sense (it asks not to use subqueries; but as you and everyone else noted, the problem is solved with a simple `join` and there is no good reason why anyone would use subqueries for it). These factors point at a homework question, for which we have [specific guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/). (The requirements are not really different from normal, but we do pay some special attention to avoiding plagiarism.)

More importantly, the question doesn't show any attempt to *understand* the task. I want to stress here that *it would be fine* to ask a question about how to join SQL tables without knowing that there is a `join` keyword or really anything about SQL beyond how to create the tables. However, there **must be some attempt to analyze** the problem, break it down into logical steps, and ensure that the problem isn't really multiple problems in one. There also needs to be *some* indication of what OP wants the code to do - in *problem* terms, not in *task* terms. Something like "I have data that associates each `studName` with a `studentid`, and each `studentid` with a `teacherid`. How can I use SQL to correlate that information, and associate `teacherid`s with `studName`s? Similarly, how can I then use the association of `teacherid` to `teacherName`, in order to associate each `studName` with a `teacherName`?" (Yes, those are two separate problems, technically; but it is the same problem both times, and - as evident in the code you provided - they can both be solved in the same breath).

Comment: "No, that is not even close to the only requirement, or to the standard expected." - agreed for 95% of the site. But for the SQL tag though... its a different subculture. The "not-exactly-programming" subculture. Questions in such topics tend to be personal support questions, it's just the way it is. I really hope someday these topics are moved out of Stack Overflow so we can stop being pedantic about it.