# How can I improve my question to remove a question ban?

Tags: support, post-ban

I run into a "circular reference" problem with my question: [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75574822/generate-list-of-n-quarters-of-years-relative-to-the-date-in-python)

I don’t have any idea how to be more specific on the problem (how to generate the list of the quarters of the year in the form QQ-YY in Python, but I have solved it now thanks to the answers received), neither can I delete the question as I got two useful answers.

From supervisors I got a notion that question has no future value. So, what if two people provided useful contributions, the question gets hits and bots consider it eligible for protection from removal?

OK, what can I do now? The only solution I see now is to delete/abandon the account and start from the beginning.

I don't have any deleted questions so far.

Comment: "The only solution I see now is to the delete/abandon the account and start from the beginning." You're not allowed to do that. If you're discovered to have created an alternate account to get around your question ban - and the moderators have ways of finding out - your new account will be suspended.

Comment: [*Deleting and recreating a new account will hurt you, not help.*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583)

Comment: I don't see the question as lacking focus. Seems to be clear and on-topic "How to" question. The closure is incorrect. The question might be a duplicate but that's still on-topic for the site. The question can be edited to present it better but should not be essential for understanding and answering the question. For example, a sample expected output can be provided for reference.

Comment: Deleted questions, score <= 0, contributing to the [question ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans): [1](//stackoverflow.com/q/74448027) [2](//stackoverflow.com/q/70172133) [3](//stackoverflow.com/q/66127213) [4](//stackoverflow.com/q/64206680) [5](//stackoverflow.com/q/62352058) [6](//stackoverflow.com/q/48022229) [7](//stackoverflow.com/q/42485468)

Comment: I've taken a shot at reformatting the question to clearly present requirements, example and especially to highlight the programming problem. That said, this looks like a very specialised problem that does not care about the underlying method (effectively, counting with wrap-around) so it might take some time until other people stumble upon it and could mark it as helpful.

Comment: “I don't have any deleted questions so far.” - You actually have to since a question ban is impossible with a single poorly received question. The only way forward is to ask a single question, once every 6 months, until you raise above the quality threshold making a question asking rate limit necessary. Improving this single question will only help if you are jus below the threshold, which is unlikely, since none of your questions appear to have been upvoted.

Comment: “The only solution I see now is to the delete/abandon the account and start from the beginning.” - This would only result in your new account also being question banned, potentially suspended, or simply deleted. Creating a new account to bypass a question ban is against the rules.

Comment: Your questions are well written, but some for reason they generate very little interest. But the [Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) questions ought to be well received (after all, it is a homework tag, where willing (or [paid](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417632/request-to-let-banned-users-ask-one-question-every-week#comment906279_417632)?) participants are dying to fulfill work orders). But they ***[can not work on images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)***; they need ***text***.

Comment: Many people consider a reasonably scoped code requirements dump to be unfocused & that an asker should say where/how they are stuck with a [mre]. (Note your requirements are not clear about the exact form of input/interface.)

Comment: \**for some reason* (the edit grace period for comments ought to be 48 hours, not 5 minutes)

Comment: Indeed, I have 7 deleted questions over the "lifetime" (7 years). So it is better to answer own question rather than delete it if I find myself "doing not enough of research"?
In the background I am thinking about research in combination with notorious ChatGPT - seems it is so exhausting, it may render support sites we all are used to, obsolete.

Comment: @JanisE: ChatGPT *can* sometimes work as a useful assistant, but in many cases ChatGPT is ***completely*** wrong and/or makes stuff up that simply isn't so (for example, function names (for a library) that do not exist). Or in other words, it is unreliable and can not be trusted for anything factual (everything it outputs ***must*** be fact checked).

Comment: I appreciate the efforts of community contributing to the explanation on how to ask a good question. Still, the derived question remains - do I still have a ban on asking new questions and whom can I ask about it without involving the public?

Answer (score 5):

> I don’t have any idea how to be more specific on the problem (how to generate the list of the quarters of the year in the form QQ-YY in Python

This is going to ramble a bit, because the point is nuanced and has some qualifiers.

When a question "Needs More Focus", that doesn't really mean that it needs to be more *specific*. (That would often fall under "Needs Details or Clarity".) There is enough information to understand what the code needs to do - although it would be better to come up with a specific format for the input (for example, suppose we start with three numbers that tell us the starting quarter, the starting year, and the number of values?).

Instead, a question that "Needs More Focus" is, in most cases, one that combines multiple logical *steps*. In other words, more *analysis* is needed in order to ask a question that is about *just one thing*.

I didn't initially vote to close this question, but as of this answer I have cast such a vote post reopening, with the same reason. In large part, programming is about breaking problems down into smaller steps, and it's possible to carry that pretty far. There is some disagreement over how focused questions really need to be; I personally lean pretty far towards the purist end of this spectrum, because it is useful for establishing good canonical questions.

At the extreme: for a long time, I found questions that I would awkwardly close as duplicates of things like [How do I multiply each element in a list by a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166633) , or [Apply function to each element of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082410) , or [Call int() function on every list element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371269) ... the key underlying idea here is "how do I (do something trivial) *with each element of a list*?", and the point is to illustrate standard techniques: using a list comprehension, an explicit `for` loop, or the built-in `map` function. The point is that the nature of "do something trivial" isn't that interesting, most of the time - most OPs do seem to know how to do whatever it is they're trying to do, with a single list element.

All of these are really instances of the same problem - but it's hard to disentangle them from the specific "do something trivial" in each individual question. Sometimes new questions come from people who actually *don't* know how to do the trivial thing for a single element, so they *really have two questions*. In the older, established questions, while yes it's nice to have an object example to talk about, it draws attention away from the iteration techniques, towards looking for more interesting (, faster, more memory-efficient, ...) ways of doing the trivial thing. There is hardly ever anything about the trivial thing, that actually informs the decision about the iteration technique. It's just a separate issue.

So eventually I ended up [writing my own self-answered question for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75666408/how-can-i-collect-the-results-of-a-repeated-calculation-in-a-list-dictionary-et) so I can use that instead - and also talk about how the *same iteration techniques* can be used for other iterables. The question is abstract, but it's focused on just the iteration technique - not on the per-element task.

In short: **when questions are properly broken down, it becomes much easier to identify and make use of duplicates**. If you need to know about AB, and someone else needs to know about AC, then having both of you break that down into the separate A, B, C parts means that both of you can be pointed at existing, high-quality Q&A for the A problem, and we don't have to repeat the work. (And then, when you ask your B-only question, that becomes something that can be helpful for the next person who has to do BD.) Also, the isolated A question is easier to explain in terms that make a really good *title*, which in turn makes it easier to find with a search engine.

Of course, exceptions are made in cases where two tasks are a really common pairing, and/or when there is *direct* support for doing both tasks at once. e.g. someone who has to [read and use JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/) in Python doesn't actually need to read the file into an ordinary string as if it were any other text file, and then use the `json` library to parse the string; instead, the `json` library can be given the open file directly and instructed to parse its contents.

---

In your case: yes, it's possible to solve the problem with a few lines of code. The question can easily be answered in the scope of a single Stack Overflow answer. And yes, we can understand what the requirements are, at least well enough to fill in the blanks.

However, it's straightforward to see that there are a few obvious logical pieces to the puzzle:

- For a given "quarter" string in the output, what should be the numeric year value? (We can figure this out in a variety of ways, but they all boil down to considering the starting point and the position within the output, and doing some math.)
- Similarly, what should be the numeric quarter value? (Similarly, we'll just be doing math.)
- If we have those numeric values, how do we create the corresponding string? (This is a string formatting task; it isn't clear to me how much you know about doing this sort of thing, but we have existing questions covering that ground - for example, [How do I put a variable’s value inside a string (interpolate it into the string)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960772) .)
- Given the ability to create an individual string for a quarter label, how do we repeat this process and make a list of the specified number of results? (Oh, would you look at that: I already discussed the existing Q&A for this! :) )

If you didn't already attempt an analysis like that before asking the question, well, [that's part of what we're looking for in good questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). (Older answers there miss the point somewhat; we don't really mind duplicating documentation that exists elsewhere, but we want the *task* to be analyzed so that it can be broken down into useful *questions*.) If you did, well - where exactly *are* you stuck?

(If you have a reasonable guess that there should be built-in library functionality for some combination of steps, and just couldn't find it in the documentation, you might try to ask anyway. Don't be too disheartened if it gets closed as Needs More Focus, or with multiple duplicate links. You still learn something this way, right? Please always keep in mind that we close, and vote on, content - not users.)

(If you *know* that there is under-appreciated library functionality that performs a common set of steps, consider writing a self-answered question to advertise that functionality. Whether something is really "separate steps" can be subjective, too. For example, the standard library's `random.choice` *could* be replaced by checking the length of the input, generating a random number, and indexing in. That's essentially what `random.choice` does under the hood, and it's the logical set of steps for solving the problem in languages that aren't as high-level as Python. But clearly in Python, using `random.choice` is a much more elegant solution - which is why it was created in the first place.)

Comment: As somebody around here says, who might be you, a proper debugging question is no longer about debugging.

Comment: Sigh, I wish you had *focused* on either the general or the specific part... ;) I agree with the general part but do not see how this applies to this question. Notably, none of the answers actually use the decomposition described in this answer (having quarter and year value, then counting in that base) – one uses the inverse (counting, then splitting that into the base) and the other uses case-specific tooling (treating it as actual dates). So the decomposition is neither obvious nor unique, and as such unreasonable to expect someone not knowing the answer to do it. […]

Comment: [...] Which ultimately ties into the same story as "what have you tried" and all that actually *being harmful*. If we expect askers to already have *a* decomposition for well-scoped problems, then we don't leave room for *other* solutions using a *different* decomposition. We don't leave room for *the same* question decomposed differently to match to its peers. Both of these are vital for the "knowledge library" to work.

Comment: "(having quarter and year value, then counting in that base) – one uses the inverse (counting, then splitting that into the base)" - not "having" quarter and year value, but *computing* them. Counting and splitting is what I had in mind, in fact. Case-specific tooling is a good reason to leave the question open, insofar as the case-specific tooling addresses the *entire* problem.

Comment: @philipxy I am indeed the one "around here who says that", yes. :)

Answer (score 3):

Current state of the linked question is "ok" and it can stay on the site just fine as well as get answered.

One thing is clear so that the question "does not show any research effort" - the lack of such information does not make it off-topic (and hence it stays open), but is the official reason and guidance to downvote such questions.

At this point you have two routes (you can pursue both at the same time):

- wait till that question get enough visitors who have the same problem and upvote the question. You'd need roughly x100-x1000 visitors per downvote (as rate of votes from visits is about 1 in 100-1000 visits) which at this (2023-05-05) time is up to 5K visitors. Based on current views (170) collecting so many visits is unlikely any time soon. Promoting post in some out-of-network way may help (i.e. make that task into list of someone's homework), promoting on meta (like you've done with this post) likely bring more critical reviews as meta visitors rarely need that exact question answered.
- figure out what "research" would be appropriate and edit the question to include it. It would make more sense to make such edit before posting the meta question, but it is not too late to do that in a day or two while the question is still relatively new on meta. It is quite commonon to receive "post your code" comments even on "how-to" (aka "do my homework") questions precisely for that reason - posting your attempted code counts as "researching" (unless it is clear *lorem ipsum* text). Indeed there are other ways to show "research" - linking to questions/articles you looked at and explaining why those did not work is another option.

Note that there are *very rare* cases when the problem is well known to experts in the field, but essentially impossible to be sensibly researched by less-experienced folks - in such cases showing research would be not useful and lack of it likely not cause downvotes. I'm 99% sure questions about grouping/filtering data (like the linked one) are not in that category and some *demostrated* research is expected to get positive vote count.